# Is it possible to remove a page from Facebook recommendations plugin?

Tags: facebook, plugins

I don't want to see one of my pages in the Facebook recommendations plugin because it isn't in use now. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Yes. There is the message: Page title. 133 people recommend this, but i don't want that page to be included

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, if you Start returning en error code when people/facebook try accessing that page and run the page through Facebook's debugger it'll stop appearing as a suggestion

Comment: Then i'm not sure - if you can access an admin page for that page (i.e a virtual 'page' on facebook for posting updates to fans of that URL) you could delete it there and potentially reset the like count to 0 - otherwise I can't think of a way - it's not really a supported use-case